# How to Set a Model value by using Variable dynamically in ASP.NET Core Razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am having **Razor view** like this

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Item>

@{
    var colList = ViewData["colList"];
}
<table>
    <thead>
        @foreach (var col in (List<Columns>)columns)
        {
            var colName = col.ColumnName;
            <th>@colName</th>
        }
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var cust in (List<Columns>)columns)
        {
            var colVal = col.ColumnID;
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@colVal">
            </td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Item Model:**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class Item
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Custom1 { get; set; }
        public string Custom2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Columns Model:**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class Columns
    {
        public string ColumnID { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in the `ColumnID` values in the table will be **Custom1** And **Custom2** so that the value of the **`ColumnID`** in the **`Columns`** table will be equal to the **`Column Name`** of the **`Item`** Table.

so in the below code variable **colVal** Value will be the **Custom1**

```
var colVal = col.ColumnID;
```

and when I put that variable in **`asp-for`** in the **input** tag the value is coming as **Custom1** not the **`value of the Custom1`** Column in **`Item`** Table like given below image. But the value of the **Custom1** in the **Item** table is **`ABC`**

```
<input asp-for="@colVal">
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I think you have it all wrong! Why would you need the Column class? Not to mention that the foreach loop is severely messed up!

Comment: Because I will decide the custom columns to be show or not for the users as per their subscription or needs.

Comment: Again, you don't need a special class for that! Just don't include those properties in the ViewModel